# GIT Bash for windows gives no result and returns to command prompt

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash, git-gui

I'm a new user of GIT on windows. I have been using GIT on linux for a while but for some reason, I need to use GIT on windows. Now my problem is GIT bash for windows does not perform any remote operation and returns to command prompt with no msgs. For eg: git fetch, git pull, git remote show origin, etc will give you no result. Where as it does give me output for local operations like git log, git branch, git commit, etc.

Also the GIT GUI Client gives error "Command Failed" for remote operations.

I tried re-installing it several times. I tried a previous version 2.5.3 of GIT as well (latest version is 2.6.0).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the result of `git remote -v`

If there is no remote defined, a push or fetch wouldn't know where to look.

You can fix the issue with a

```
git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo
```

If the normal setup doesn't work for you, uninstall, and then unzip [PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\bin` to `%PATH%`.

Then, from the repo root folder, try a `git ls-remote` to see if the remote '`origin`' is accessible.

If there are errors like:

```
Faulting application name: git-remote-https.exe, version: 2.6.0.0, 
time stamp: 0x00000000 
Faulting module name: LIBEAY32.dll, version: 1.0.2.4, 
time stamp: 0x00000000
```

Try and follow [issue 133 comment](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/133#issuecomment-100831754). Copy:

```
c:\winprg\git-sdk-64\mingw64\bin\ssleay32.dll
c:\winprg\git-sdk-64\mingw64\bin\libeay32.dll
to
c:\Windows\System32\
```

Comment: git remote -v gives proper url. :(

Comment: Good thinking ;) Let's wait for the OP's feedback now.

Comment: @VinayKumarTiwary is it an https url or an ssh one?

Comment: @VonC I tried your suggested steps. Unfortunately, this is also not working. The application crashes every time I try a remote operation. I looked in event viewer for detailed error and found this. Faulting application name: git-remote-https.exe, version: 2.6.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Faulting module name: LIBEAY32.dll, version: 1.0.2.4, time stamp: 0x00000000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91499/discussion-between-vinay-tiwary-and-vonc).

Comment: @VinayTiwary Is it a Windows 7 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: its windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @Vinay Tiwary you got the solution of this problem ??. i am facing the same thing but not able to find the solution on google. if you got it please let me know here. i have remote repository configured properly

Comment: @AnkitMongia What version of Git and Windows are you using? What is your remote URL (HTTPS? or SSH?)

Comment: @VonC git version -- 2.21 (64 bit) , Windows -- 64 bit and remote URL -- SSH

Comment: @AnkitMongia Does the issue persists with 2.26.2?

Comment: @VonC do you have any other answer to it ??

Comment: @AnkitMongia I do not: I suggest adding a new separate question, with your specific details, in order for others to investigate.

Comment: @VonC Already done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636918/git-pull-or-fetch-behaves-differently-every-time-i-run-these-commands-on-git-bas?noredirect=1#comment109029688_61636918