# git pull or fetch behaves differently every time i run these commands on git bash for windows

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

git pull and git fetch behaves in 4 different ways listed below

1.) Returns nothing and display the command prompt. I checked the exit code it comes out to be 1.
2.) Fails with error "remote end hung up unexpectedly, early EOF's unpack objects failed.
3.) Fails with error "remote end hung up unexpectedly bad pack header.
4.) Execute successfully some time.

For point number 2 and 3 i tried various solutions (editing the config file) given on internet but still the issue persists. can someone help me resolve all the issues listed above in one answer??

git version -- 2.21 (64 bit) , Windows -- 64 bit and remote URL -- SSH

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like network problems that ends up on strange behavior.

Comment: @Philippe But not returning anything after running git pull can not be a network problem. I am working on a good internet speed.